# Aloe species identification

Tags: botany, species-identification, plant-anatomy

I am trying to find out which species these are.  Someone claimed they were Aloe Vera, but I am skeptical as I have never seen Aloe Vera with that kind of growth. These look more like Aloe Juvenna to me.

What do you think?

[image: Aloe plants]

Comment: Definitely not Aloe vera.

Comment: Try here: http://www.succulentguide.com/cactus/?genus=Aloe

Comment: Also please update if they decide to flower :)